# What is the potential difference between the plates? field around the plates? charge is on each plate?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, charge, capacitance, voltage

What is the potential difference between the plates? field around the plates?  charge is on each plate? 
[image]

Comment: Are you asking for definitions? Are you asking us to point to the bits in the picture that correspond to the concepts? Not very clear what you want...

Comment: What is it? It is your homework.

Comment: Hi Eli and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: While Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).